# Android: SwipeRefreshLayout cause RecyclerView not update when take screenshot?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

First, I am creating an app the need to something like transparent activity + blur like in iOS.

I decided to user getDrawingcache of an entire window

```
        View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
        decorView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        decorView.buildDrawingCache();
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(decorView.getDrawingCache());
        decorView.destroyDrawingCache();
        decorView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and then do some blur method [(stack blur)](http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlurDemo.html) and set background of new activity like this

```
        activity.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
```

This approach is works very good except when my original activity contains [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). The result i got is always return the same bitmap from first time I launched new activity

eg. First time activity launched, background image set correctly. But after that (2nd, 3rd and so on... ) background image is the same as first one.

I need help for this, any suggestion will be much appreciate, Thank you!!

If the title is not good, you can edit it freely.

UPDATE..

after couple of days of investigate this issue, I found out that real cause is SwipeRefreshLayout. My my screenshot won't update after the first time onRefreshListener called.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

Adding:

```
        mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mRecyclerView.layout(0,0,mRecyclerView.getWidth(),mRecyclerView.getHeight());

                if (mRecyclerView.isDrawingCacheEnabled())
                {
                    mRecyclerView.destroyDrawingCache();
                }
            }
        },50);
```

after `mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);` solved the problem for me

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try your method :)
But actually if avoid this problem by using alternate library
you can try too
https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-Ultra-Pull-To-Refresh